# Continious ubuntu malfunction

Tags: 14.04, firefox, login, crash

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS and I am experiencing a lot of various persistent issues for last few months.

Every of the issues is already solved here, but in my case help is always only temporary. That is the reason for this question, maybe one of you will see some deeper problem in my issues.

**The bad:** Firefox crashes really often. Also the window "report the firefox crash" crashes. Firefox always starts with "this is embarrassing message" if starts at all (https://support.mozilla.org/cs/questions/956252). I tried to use Chrome instead of firefox, but it crashes also. Seems that their crash times are synced most of the time, when is impossible to start firefox, chrome does not work either (but it is not a rule). After the worst crash attacks the installed plugins (adblock, zotero) disappear and I need to reinstall it.

**The worst:**
System get back to login screen immediately after login sometimes (something like [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)). I have not find any rule when it happens - mostly help just to restart computer (few times). Two times in past I solved it with advice from askubuntu, but the problem reappeared after some time.

**The annoying:**
I am randomly getting errors like "The update information is outdated...", when I call "apt-get update" I get error about broken files telling me that for repair I should call "apt-get update" - that is really cruel joke. The solutions from askubuntu work just temporarily if at all.

**The others:**
Sometimes system freeze and only solution is to restart (no way to switch to terminal). If I remeber, last occurencies were when I was using "files" and "audacity". For sure I forget some other issues. I will try to update this question soon.

If you have an idea, please share the information with my. I can put here any error message or system information you need (I just do not know where to start, because problem is so complex).

I am using ubuntu for about ten years and I have never experienced madness like this. And if I have to live with malfunctioning system, I would probably do not need ubuntu anymore, windows will be just fine.

**UPDATE #1**

I tried the Videonauth suggestion yesterday:

> sudo apt-get --reinstall firefox
>
> apt-get -f install

Today after login I get three different errors:

1. Sorry the application apt-get stop working unexpectedly
2. Sorry, Ubuntu 14.04 experienced an internal error
3. after minimizing and maximizing the error window it stays in smallest
   possible size (just the exit cross), and I do not rember what was there

After I tried to report the first problem, the problem report crash also.

Comment: Will firefox aswelll crash when you remove your user prppofile by `mv ~/.mozilla/firefox ~/mozilla/.firefox.bak && sudo apt-get --reinstall firefox`and then starting it again. dont worry all your profile data from FF is still in the .bak folder. Aswell you could try to run an `sudo apt-get -f install`to fix possible damaged packages.

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: Have you tested your RAM and checked your HDD? When known solutions fail and problems are intermittent I start looking closely at hardware. I've seen stuck RAM bits and failing hard disk sectors cause odd problems as well as power supplies with a weak rail.

Comment: @ElderGeek You have been correct, the RAM was the issue. Please create an answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a hardware problem.

Choose the RAM test (memtest86+) from the GRUB boot menu. Run the test to determine if you have a bad stick of RAM. If you have multiple sticks and are having trouble determining which is to blame based on the failing address, test one stick at a time.

If the RAM passes check smart status of the drive as shown [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/528072/how-can-i-check-the-smart-status-of-a-drive-on-ubuntu-14-04-through-16-04)

If that passes have someone qualified test the power supply output to determine if power output is out of spec.